# Message embed field values must be non-empty strings

Tags: discord.js

https://pastebin.com/FWYFSdfD

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
 
module.exports = {
name: 'warn',
description: 'warn a member',
async execute(message, args){
    edited = message.content.slice(5);
 
    const guildID = message.guild.Discord
    const UserId = message.member.Discord
    const Reason = args.splice(1).join('')
    let User = message.mentions.users.first()
 
    if(message.member.permissions.has('KICK_MEMBERS')){
        try{
            member = await message.guild.members.find(message.mentions.users.first())
 
        }catch(err){
                const warnEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("**Warn**")
                    .setColor("#FF0000")
                    .addField('text', 'value')
                    .addField("User:", User, true)
                    .addField("Reason:", Reason, true)
                    .setThumbnail("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRGagFW_bh2AfgI1BqAis81CXVg37j8_MKtwg&usqp=CAU")
                    .setTimestamp()
        }
        try{
            User.send(warnEmbed)
            message.channel.send(warnEmbed)
        }
        catch(err){
            return(message.reply('You must format the command <@mention> <reason>'))
        }
    }
    else{
        message.channel.send('only staff can use this command')
    }
    }
}
```

This is the warn code. But when I try to use it, I get an error saying MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings. And how many words do I need to write to send this.

Comment: It would be better if you add the code as a snippet and describe your problem more elaborately.

Comment: Does this fix your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63522144/messageembed-field-values-may-not-be-empty

Comment: Do you provide a reason to your warn? if not try doing so and add a check before adding the field like if(Reason) { warnEmbed.addField("Reason", Reason, true); }